# What are the consequences of alternative type-theoretic definition of homotopy equivalence?

Tags: homotopy-theory, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, univalent-foundations

The standard definition of *homotopy* equivalence in HoTT is a quadruple of:

- $f: A \rightarrow B$
- $g: B \rightarrow A$
- $p: \operatorname{id} A = g \circ f$
- $q: \operatorname{id} B = f \circ g$

... where the paths are homogeneous in $A \rightarrow A$ and $B \rightarrow B$ respectively.

My question is what happens if we let the paths be heterogeneous (or in the HoTT book terminology dependent) over some paths $P: (A \rightarrow A) = (A \rightarrow A)$ and $Q: (B \rightarrow B) = (B \rightarrow B)$?

Will it have practical implications for the theory (in comparison to HoTT or CTT), or will the difference be limited to the corresponding categorical semantics?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... What do you mean by "the paths are homogenous in $A \to A$ and $B \to B$"? The expression $(A \to A) = (A \to A)$ is not a valid type, so I can't reverse engineer what you mean either.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I mean by them a path in the universe: $P: (A \rightarrow A) =_U (A \rightarrow A)$ is a loop based on the type of endomorphisms of $A$. A particular inhabitant is $\operatorname{refl} (A \rightarrow A)$, but there are possibly nontrivial paths as well. So my question is if there are some significant differences between the standard h-equivalence type and a type which is the same, except that the paths between the identity and quasi-inverse compositions can be heterogeneous over such $P$, (eg. cubical-style: $p: x =^P y$ gives $p i : P i$ for $i : \mathbb{I}$).

Comment: aaaaaaah. Thank you for clarifying ^_^ I haven't thought about this before, but I'll give it a go later tonight. If I don't get it though, I'm sure somebody else will answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition might be an interesting thing, but it's not a definition of anything that most people would call an "equivalence".  You're basically saying consider two types $A$ and $B$ and functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ such that there is an automorphism of the type $A\to A$ that sends $g\circ f$ to $\rm id_A$ and an automorphism of the type $B\to B$ that sends $f\circ g$ to $\rm id_B$.

This situation holds, for instance, when $A = \mathbf{1}$ is the unit type and $B = \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{1} = \mathsf{Bool}$ is the two-element type.  In this case $B\to B$ is a finite 4-element type, which is "transitive" in that it has an automorphism sending any element to any other element — and of course $A\to A$ is also (equivalent to) a contractible type.  Most people would not consider these two types to be equivalent.  (-: